# How can I disable SVN completely in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

Since I prefer to use the CLI instead of the Eclipse plugin I would like to disable it completely.

Since I am unable to find any settings to do this, I just uninstalled through `Help > Installation Details > Installed Software` all SVN related plugins (and restarted my computer).

After removing the plugins, SVN is still present. On the projects I can still choose `Team > SVN actions` and SVN is also still in the preferences view.

So how can I disable it?

Comment: How did you uninstall all SVN related plugins?

Comment: @howlger I have edited my question.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't overlook the Subversive/Subclipse features (search/filter for `sub`)?

Comment: @howlger I searched for "sub", and there was one more plugin that's making use of Subversion. It looks like it is disabled now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you have not overlooked any Subversive/Subclipse** feature that has no *SVN* in its name: filter/search for `sub`.